# How to generate a char randomly between 'X' and 'O'?

Tags: java, random, stringbuffer

public static String generate(){

```
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < TicTacToeUtil.NUM_OF_SPACES + 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < TicTacToeUtil.NUM_OF_SPACES + 1; j++) {
            stringBuffer.append("1");
        }
        stringBuffer.append(" ");
    }
    String finalString = stringBuffer.toString();
    return finalString;
}
```

the code above is basically a game, NUM_OF_SPACES = 2, so the print will be "111 111 111",but , I want to replace all the 1s by either 'X' or 'O', which is randomly chosen between these two char. For example,"XOX XOO OOO", this is generated randomly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if you have a 50/50 chance to pick either `X` or `O`...

Comment: (Hint: That was the hint. How do you write something that goes one way 50% of the time and the other way the other 50% of the time? It involves randomness...)

Comment: Note that you should generally prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer`, as the latter is unnecessarily synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Random#nextBoolean()` method to get either `true` or `false` randomly. If the value is `true`, append `'X`. Otherwise append `'O'`:

```
public static String generate()
{
    Random r = new Random(); // create a Random object
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 + 1; j++) {
            if (r.nextBoolean()) {  // r.nextBoolean() return 'true' or 'false'
                stringBuilder.append("X");
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("O");
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.append(" ");
    }
    String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
    return finalString; // return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random` class to generate random numbers. Here I used `nextBoolean()` method from Random class to generate boolean value randomly.

```
public static String generate() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Random r = new Random(); // create a Random object
    for (int i = 0; i <TicTacToeUtil.NUM_OF_SPACES+ 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <TicTacToeUtil.NUM_OF_SPACES + 1; j++) {
            if (r.nextBoolean()) {  // r.nextBoolean() return 'true' or 'false'
                stringBuilder.append("X");
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("O");
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.append(" ");
    }
    String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
    return finalString;
}
```

I selected a value for `TicTacToeUtil.NUM_OF_SPACES` as `2` and the output was like follows,

`XXX XOO XXX`

I replaced `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder` as it's common practice. ( I think `StringBuffer` class is replicated. )